# Use image from firebase storage as src for img element React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I have a 'reviews' collection in firestore and for each one, I am trying to retrieve the url of an image from firestore and set it as 'src' for an image.
Here is the image (the image's name is the doc ID of the review):
[image]

Here is the ProductReviews components:

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import { ProductReviewCard } from './ProductReviewCard'
import {db, query, collection, getDocs, where, doc, getDoc, auth, updateDoc, arrayRemove, arrayUnion, addDoc} from '../firebase';

const MainContainer = styled.div`
display:flex;
align-items: center;
height:70vh;
marginLeft:50px;
justify-content:center;
flex-direction:column;
`

export const ProductReviews = (uniqueProductName) => {

    const [reviews, setReviews]=React.useState([]);

    const getReviews=async()=>{
        let reviewsClone=[];
        const q = query(collection(db, "reviews"), where("product", "==", uniqueProductName.product));
        const querySnapshot=await getDocs(q);
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc)=>{
            reviewsClone.push(doc.id);
        })
        setReviews(reviewsClone);

    }

    React.useEffect(()=>{
        getReviews();
    }, [])

  return (
     <MainContainer>
         {reviews.map(review => <ProductReviewCard reviewId={review}/>)} 
     </MainContainer>
  )
}
```

Here is the ProductReviewCard component

```
import React from 'react'
import styled from 'styled-components'
import StarRatings from 'react-star-ratings';
import {db, query, collection, getDocs, where, doc, getDoc, auth, updateDoc, arrayRemove, arrayUnion, addDoc, storage, ref, getDownloadURL} from '../firebase';
const StyledCard = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex:1;
  width:60%;
  height:100%;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius:5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  //margin: 30px 50px 50px 40px;
  margin-bottom:20px;
  background-size: 100%;
  opacity:1;
  flex-direction:row;
`

const Image = styled.img`
height:100%;
width:150px;
object-fit:cover;
border-top-left-radius:5px;
border-bottom-left-radius:5px;
marginLeft:30px;
flex:0.1
`
const CardContainer=styled.div`
display:flex;
flex-direction:column;
padding:0px;
margin-left:30px;
`



export const ProductReviewCard = (reviewId) => {

   const [review, setReview]=React.useState([]);
   const [imgUrl, setImgUrl]=React.useState('');
    const getReview=async()=>{
        console.log(reviewId)
        const docRef = doc(db, "reviews", reviewId.reviewId);
        const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
        if (docSnap.exists()) {
            setReview(docSnap.data())
          } else {
            console.log("No such document!");
          }

    }

    const getImage=()=>{
        getDownloadURL(ref(storage, 'gs://skince-86812.appspot.com/reviews'+reviewId.reviewId+'.jpg'))
        .then((url) => {
         console.log(url)
         setImgUrl(url);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          // Handle any errors
        });
    }
    React.useEffect(()=>{
        getReview();
        getImage();
    },[])
  return (
    <StyledCard>
        <Image src={require(imgUrl)}/>
        <CardContainer>
            <p style={{marginBottom:'0%', marginTop:'0%', fontWeight:'bold'}}>{review.user}</p>
            <p>{review.date}</p>
            <StarRatings
          rating={review.rating}
          starRatedColor="#f0e3c1"
          numberOfStars={5}
          name='rating'
          starDimension='15px'
           starHoverColor="#f0e3c1"
        />
            <p>{review.review}</p>
        </CardContainer>
        </StyledCard>
  )
}
```

(I have to mention that the retrieval of the review works perfectly fine, but when I tried to also retrieve the image, I got the following errors in Console). And I also tried with ref(storage, 'reviews/'+reviewId.reviewId+'.jpg'), but still nothing. These are the console errors.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Returning an image from Firebase storage within Reactjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71555650/returning-an-image-from-firebase-storage-within-reactjs). Also check out this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#full_example) for a full example and make sure your security rules allow reading the files.

Comment: Please include errors as TEXT please so it will be searchable. That will enable future readers to locate the question.